# bind sobject picklist values to html5 select tag

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object say preferences__c which has a picklist called country__c with some values in it.
The visualforce page is something like this.

```
<apex:page StandardController="preferences__c" docType="html-5.0">
```

The page has a HTML5 select tag. when the page loads I need to bind field values of picklist country__c to the select tag. I admit I am a novice to this, any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please add VF Page code!

Comment: <apex:page StandardController="preferences__c"
           docType="html-5.0"><head>table> <select name="Country">
                <option value="USA">USA</option> The value "USA" should come from field country__c.

Comment: If you are using standardController, you can use apex:inputField tag, rest rendering VF compiler will going to take care:
<apex:inputField value="{!preferences__c.country__c}"/>

Comment: U mean just remove the HTML5 select tag and replace it with <apex:selectOptions> tag

Comment: remove HTML5 tag and you can use this:
<apex:inputField value="{!preferences__c.country__c}"/>

Comment: thnx. that worked

Comment: @RSG Why remove the HTML5 tag? Using the Input Field helper would work just as well with it?

Comment: @DanJones Then there will be two select tags on UI, one will HTML5 select tag and other will be inputField one. Better we will use apex tags if we have.

Comment: @RSG I don't fully understand you. The doctype just defines what version of HTML the browser should use. `<apex:inputField>` is just a helper the writes HTML on the page for you. You would just need to remove `<select><option value="something">Something</select>`, if it's on there, and use the `<apex:inputField>` that will write the select HTML and options for you.

Comment: @DanJones Yes I asked her to remove this HTML tag <select><option value="something">Something</select> only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove HTML5 tag and you can use this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!preferences__c.country__c}"/>
```